# Return value of a Property from child ViewModel to parent ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

In my WPF MVVM app, using Caliburn.Micro, I have a ViewModel, `CreateServiceViewModel` that, on a button click, opens a GridView in a seperate window for the User to chose a Row from.

I created another ViewModel for this, `MemberSearchViewModel` which has two properties:

```
    private Member selectedMember;

    public Member SelectedMember
    {
        get { return selectedMember; }
        set { selectedMember = value; }
    }

    private IList<Member> members;

    public IList<Member> Members
    {
        get { return members; }
        set { members = value; }
    }
```

How do I get that SelectedMember value back to the calling ViewModel?  That ViewModel has a property of `Service.SelectedMember`.

Comment: I'd avoid creating dependencies between the 2 VMs, if possible.  If you're using Prism or similar, the EventAggregator, or a similar pattern, may be useful.

Comment: I'm using Caliburn.Micro.  Probably should have mentioned that... It seems like, either, the `EventAggregater` or the `IChild` implementation could help me here but I just can't wrap my head around how...

Comment: For further reference, all I need from this ViewModel is the Selected GridView row.  It pops up, user chooses a row, it closes.

Comment: I put some code in an answer format.  Let me know if you need more.

Comment: In general, then, is it better to use an event in this situation versus passing the value back to it's parent directly?

Comment: I like using them between VMs.  If not then the 2 are coupled.  The coupling might be okayto some people when they are in the same module, but if they need to be factored into separate modules(dll) at a later time, then you could have a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EventAggregator is what you could use... One of many solutions I am sure.

```
public class MessageNotifier{
  public object Content{get;set;}
  public string Message {get;set;}
}


//MEF bits here
public class HelloWorldViewModel: Screen, IHandle<MessageNotifier>{
   private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator

  //MEF constructor bits
  public YourViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator){
    _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
  }

   public override OnActivate(){
       _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
   }
   public override OnDeactivate(){
     _eventAggregator.UnSubscribe(this);
   }

   //I Handle all messages with this signature and if the message applies to me do something
   //
   public void Handle(MesssageNotifier _notifier){
        if(_notifier.Message == "NewSelectedItem"){
            //do something with the content of the selectedItem
            var x = _notifier.Content
        }
   } 
}

//MEF attrs
public class HelloWorld2ViewModel: Screen{
   private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator
    //MEF attrs
    public HelloWorld2ViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator){
       _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    public someobject SelectedItem{
      get{ return _someobject ;}
      set{ _someobject = value;
          NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>SelectedItem);
          _eventAggregator.Publish(new MessageNotifier(){ Content = SelectedItem, Message="NewSelectedItem"});
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used variations of this extensively.  It makes exchanging messages/information between ViewModels a breeze.

Comment: Cool, this definetly works.  Few follow up questions if I may.  Is this specific to Caliburn Micro?  Just curious... Also, is the `OnActivate` and `OnDeactivate` required or considered best practice.  The CM documentation seemed to say it wasn't required except for specific cases.  Lastly, your thoughts on using the `MessageNotifier` class versus implementing specific `Handle<T>`'s.  Have you found it more flexible, simpler, etc.  Thanks again!

Comment: The pattern is not specific to CM, there are lots of differing implementations. Obviously you need to control subscription to the aggregator or you could have VMs receiving messages that aren't supposed to be getting them, but this control is up to you to decide on. I prefer the `IHandle<T>` approach myself, just feels simple but flexible

Comment: This is just an example of the pattern but the exact implementation is specific to Caliburn.Micro.  I use the OnActivate/Deactivate to have it mark for GC but it doesn't have been done.

Comment: There are other possibilities that I wasn't sure on, did you use a windowmanager call to display the window?  If so then you have access to the results of the window, for which you can embed the SelectedMember.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to utilize `NotifyPropertyChanged`.  Since you are working with ViewModels, they most likely implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which you can make use of just as the framework does.

When your CreateServiceViewModel creates the MemberSearchViewModel, it would just subscribe to the PropertyChanged event:

```
//This goes wherever you create your child view model
var memberSearchViewModel = new MemberSearchViewModel(); //Or using a service locator, if applicable
memberSearchViewModel.PropertyChanged += OnMemberSearchPropertyChanged;

private void OnMemberSearchPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == "SelectedMember")
    {
        //Code to respond to a change in the Member
    }
}
```

And then in your MemberSearchViewModel, you simply raise the NotifyPropertyChanged event when the user has selected a member from the grid.

EDIT:
As @DNH correctly notes in the comments, using event handlers like this can lead to memory leaks if not properly cleaned up.  So when you are finished with the MemberSearchViewModel, make sure to unsubscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event.  So for example, if you only need it until the user selects a member, you could put it inside the Property Changed Handler itself (I've switched it to use a class-level variable to hold the ViewModel):

```
private void OnMemberSearchPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == "SelectedMember")
    {
        //Code to respond to a change in the Member

        //Unsubscribe so the view model can be garbage collected
        _memberSearchViewModel.PropertyChanged -= OnMemberSearchPropertyChanged;
        _memberSearchViewModel = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Smells like a fine memory leak. You will have to remove the event handler, when the `memberSearchViewModel` is no longer needed. Otherwise, it will remain in memory as long the listening VM is existing.

Comment: Agreed, EventHandlers are common sources of memory leaks, but without knowing more of the architecture, I can't say when the parent should unsubscribe.  I'll add a note to the answer to make sure this is called out explicitly, though.  Thanks for calling attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to store `MemberSearchViewModel` as a field of `CreateServiceViewModel` and define `CreateServiceViewModel.SelectedMember` property as follows:

```
public Member SelectedMember
{
    get
    {
        return _memberSearchViewModel.SelectedMember;
    }
    set
    {
        _memberSearchViewModel.SelectedMember = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
public interface INotifyMe<T>
{
    T ResultToNotify { get; set; }
}

public class CreateServiceViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyMe<Member>
{
    // implement the interface as you like...
}

public class MemberSearchViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MemberSearchViewModel(INotifyMe<Member> toBeNotified)
    {
        // initialize field and so on...
    }
}
```

Now you could let listen `CreateServiceViewModel` to its own property and you won't have to think about the removal of the event listener.

Well of course to do the more classical way you could alternatively use an interface like this.

```
public interface INotifyMe<T>
{
    void Notify(T result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to my comment, here's an example using `Prism` - I've never used `Caliburn`.

**Create an event** - the event's payload will be your SelectedMember:

```
public class YourEvent:CompositePresentationEvent<YourEventPayload>{}
```

**Publish the event:**

```
EventAggregator.GetEvent<YourEvent>().Publish(YourEventPayload);
```

**Subscribe to the event:**

```
EventAggregator.GetEvent<YourEvent>().Subscribe((i) => ...);
```